# can not convert from System.Collection.Generic.List<Dal.Questio> to Dal.Questio

Tags: c#, linq

I want to append my list into another list but when i do this i got the error

How can it be solved?

```
public List<Questio> Get(int Id)
{
    List<Questio> Quest;
    Quest = null;
    try
    {
        using (db = new Entities())
        {
            var Qu = db.Que.Where(x => x.Lan == Id).Select(i => i.Id);

            foreach (var a in Qu)
            {
                var ID = db.Quess.Where(x => x.QueId == a).Select(i => i.Qued);

                foreach (var j in ID)
                {
                    var vv = db.Questio.Where(m => m.QId == j).ToList();
                    Quest.Add(vv);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lists are added with `.AddRange` not `.Add`

Comment: There's a bunch of tings wrong with this code. You're not returning anything. The `Quest` variable is never initialise so will throw null reference exception. `vv` is an enumerable, not a single item. etc. etc. What exactly do you want this code to do? I'm sure there's an easier way.

Comment: please, please, revise your variable naming. your code looks like alphabet soup. the  fix though, as mentioned in other comments.

Comment: @SiavashRostami You mean you don't know the difference between `Quest`, `Qu`, `a`, `j`, `Quess` and `Questio`?

Comment: @DavidG you are right i assigned null to Quest in order to initialize it but it will not work

Comment: but is there a way i can initialize Quest so that i can add list to it

Comment: @DavidG kinda forgot how to spell my name after reading these names

Comment: @JoeSmith, yes, but then `Quest` becomes a list of lists. Is that what you actually need?

Comment: @Andrei yes that is what i want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use `AddRange` that accepts `IEnumerable`:

```
Quest.AddRange(vv);
```

`Add` is for adding a single item only.

If what you actually need is a list of lists, then declare `Quest` differently:

```
List<List<Questio>> Quest = new List<List<Questio>>();
...

var vv = db.Questio.Where(m => m.QId == j).ToList();
Quest.Add(vv);
```

Now your call to `Add` should work fine.

Two side notes, both beyond the scope of the question: 1) as the comments say, please review your naming; 2) this code could be simplified with more LINQ features, like Join and SelectMany.

Comment: am i still need to initialize Quest as null as i am getting the error of can not convert  System.collection.generic.list to system.collection.generic.ienumrable....

Comment: @JoeSmith, no, not as null. you want to initialize it as an empty collection

Comment: and  on using  List<Questio> i am getting use of unassigned var error

Comment: how can it be initialize  as empty collection

Comment: @JoeSmith, notice this `= new List<List<Questio>>();` that I have in the answer? this is the way to initialize Quest properly

Comment: but then i am getting the error of can not convert System.collection.generic.list to system.collection.generic.ienumrable....